# Play framework JSON reads: How to read either String or Int?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

JS client of rest api can send both int and string as a value of some field.

```
{
   field1: "123",
   field2: "456"
}

{
   field1: 123,
   field2: 456
}
```

Here is play action with case class to which json request body should be converted:

```
  case class Dto(field1: Int, field2: Int)
  object Dto {
    implicit val reads = Json.reads[Dto]
  } 

  def create = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[Dto].map {
      dto => someService.doStuff(dto).map(result => Ok(Json.toJson(result)))
    }.recoverTotal {
      e => jsErrorToBadRequest(e)
    }
  }
```

In case if I send json values with int values, it works ok. But in case if field1 or field2 are strings ("123", "456"), it fails, because request.body.validate expects Int.

But problem is that JS client sends values from input fields, and input fields are converted to strings.

What is the best way to handle either ints or strings? (So this action should convert json to dto in both cases)

Answer (score 8):

You could also define a more tolerant `Reads[Int]`.
And use it to define your `Reads[Dto]`

1) Define a more tolerant `Reads[Int]`:

```
  import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import scala.util.{Success, Try}

  // Define a more tolerant Reads[Int]
  val readIntFromString: Reads[Int] = implicitly[Reads[String]]
      .map(x => Try(x.toInt))
      .collect (ValidationError(Seq("Parsing error"))){
          case Success(a) => a
      }

 val readInt: Reads[Int] = implicitly[Reads[Int]].orElse(readIntFromString)
```

Examples:

```
readInt.reads(JsNumber(1))
// JsSuccess(1,)

readInt.reads(JsString("1"))
//  JsSuccess(1,)

readInt.reads(JsString("1x"))
// JsError(List((,List(ValidationError(List(Parsing error),WrappedArray())))
```

2) Use your more tolerant `Reads[Int]` to define your `Reads[Dto]`:

```
implicit val DtoReads = 
    (JsPath \ "field1").read[Int](readInt) and 
    (JsPath \ "field2").read[Int](readInt)
```

EDIT: Differences with millhouse's solution:

- if `field1` is a *string* and `field2` is an *int* with this solution you'll get a `JsSuccess` but a `JsError` with millhouse's solution
- If both field are invalid with this solution you'll get a `JsError` containing one error for each field. With millhouse's solution you'll get the first error.

Comment: On play 2.6 use `JsonValidationError` instead of `ValidationError`

Answer (score 3):

It is actually quite easy with `or` combinator (documented here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) and little reads function.

```
case class Customer(name: String, number: Int)

object Customer {
  val readIntFromString: Reads[Int] = implicitly[Reads[String]]
    .map(x => x.toInt)

  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val routeReads: Reads[Customer] =
    ((__ \ "name").read[String] and
      ((__ \ "number").read[Int] or
        (__ \ "number").read[Int](readIntFromString)))(Customer.apply _)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom `Reads` implementation for your `Dto` - i.e. a `Reads[Dto]`. I always like to start with the "built-in" (macro-generated) one you get via `Json.reads[Dto]` - and then go from there; e.g.:

```
object Dto {
  val basicReads = Json.reads[Dto]

  implicit val typeCorrectingReads = new Reads[Dto]{

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Dto] = {

      def readAsInteger(fieldName:String):JsResult[Int] = {
        (json \ fieldName).validate[String].flatMap { s =>
          // We've got a String, but it might not be convertible to an int...
          Try(s.toInt).map(JsSuccess(_)).getOrElse {
            JsError(JsPath \ fieldName, s"Couldn't convert string $s to an integer")
          }
        }
      }

      basicReads.reads(json).orElse {
        for {
          f1 <- readAsInteger("field1")
          f2 <- readAsInteger("field2")
        } yield {
          Dto(f1, f2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By doing it this way, you get the `basicReads` to do the work in the "happy case". If it doesn't work out, we then try treating the fields as `String` instances, before finally attempting the conversion to an `Int`.

Note how wherever possible, we're working inside the scope of a `JsResult` that was created by "somebody else", so we'll fail fast.